# Hide and show back button in navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, back-button, navigationitem

I have these two methods:

```
func showSpinner()
{
    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .White)
    spinner.startAnimating()

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: spinner)
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}

func hideSpinner()
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` I call `showSpinner` and then after data loaded I call `hideSpinner`. But backButton often jumping on `hideSpinner`. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: you can use this method `- (void)setHidesBackButton:(BOOL)hidesBackButton animated:(BOOL)animated;` to show the back button using animation

Comment: Already tried the same result.

Comment: Have you tried to show the back button with some delay like 0.2 or as per the requirement like this- `func hideSpinner()
    {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        dispatch_after(1, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
        };
    }`

Comment: Thank you it's works, you can write is as answer, but I don't understand why it happens?

Comment: Bcos you are trying to do two tasks remove spinner and show back button at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use delay to show the back button after removing the spinner. Like 0.2 seconds or as per the requirement

```
func hideSpinner()
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    dispatch_after(1, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
    };
}
```